# google-cloud get instance id and zone with python api

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-python

How can I get the current running instanceId, and it's zone in the running Python application.

In Go and Java it's done in the following way, what is the equivilant in Python?

Go,

```
import metadata "cloud.google.com/go/compute/metadata"

func main(){
    println(metadata.InstanceID))
}
```

Java

```
String instanceId = com.google.cloud.MetadataConfig.getInstanceId()
```

Comment: The Metadata Service is not consistently exposed through higher-level language SDKs. However, it's straightforward to construct the HTTP request directly to get the Instance metadata that you need. See here: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/storing-retrieving-metadata#project_and_instance_metadata

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found an easy solution:

```
 requests.get("http://metadata/computeMetadata/v1/instance/id",
         headers={'Metadata-Flavor': 'Google'}).text
```

Comment: More info about querying for vm metadata is available here: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/metadata/querying-metadata

Answer (score 1):

In Python it will require a little bit more coding. Here is what you need to do, to list all the instances in Google Compute Engine. Instance's ID and zone.

1. In [Using the Python Client Library](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/python-guide) documentation you can see the example code for `Create`, `List` and `Delete` an instance. There is also a link to the GitHub for the entire source code.
2. To list the instances, you need the `PROJECT_ID` and the `ZONE`. Which means that you have to list all the available `ZONES` first and then list all the instances in each `ZONE` if available. Refer to the [Regions and Zones](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/regions-zones/) documentation for all the available zones and to [Method: zones.list](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/zones/list#examples) for the Python code to list them.

I did a little bit of coding my self and I have a code that worked for me. You can find my [code example here](https://github.com/andrikosrikos/Google-Cloud-Support/blob/master/GCE/list_instances.py).

NOTE: The code will take some time to execute, since it is looking for all the possible available instances in each available `ZONE`.